# How to stop media player properly , android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have created a list of songs on click on the song i am able to play the song using MedaiPlayer. While one song is playing if the user clicks another song then i am stopping the media player and starting the player again. But I am getting illegalstateexception in reset(). Here is the code where I am getting the exception. How to stop a player properly? also why am i getting this exception. How to avoid it?

```
public void stopPlayer() {
        try {
            if (player != null) {
                // Log.e("Trying to Stop "," Player ");
                player.stop();
                player.release();

                player.reset();// causes IllegalstateException

                player = null;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            player = null;
            playerStatus = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `player.release()` causes to release the MediaPlayer object, so you cannot reset it afterward, because you don't have the object to reset it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this :

```
player.reset();
player.release();
```

and also have a look at media player [state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: I was experiencing some problems, using these methods in this order under finally block solved them. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to play again ,then use `player.reset()`,
`player.release()` means that it releases the player object so you have to re-intialise  the player. So first you use `reset()` and then `release()`. `release()` is used when your player object no longer working. When your activity destroys `release()` method to be used for good practice.

Whenever you want to stop it:

```
if(player!=null)
{
   if(player.isPlaying())
      player.stop();

   player.reset();//It requires again setDataSource for player object.

}
```

Whenever your player no longer to be needed:

```
if(player!=null)
{
   if(player.isPlaying())
      player.stop();

   player.reset();//It requires again setDataSource for player object.
   player.release();
   player=null; // fixed typo.

}
```

Answer (score 4):

***Though the accepted answer works, This is a better way to achieve the task***

```
private void stopSong() {

        if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();// It requires again setDataSource for player object.
                mediaPlayer.stop();// Stop it
                mediaPlayer.release();// Release it
                mediaPlayer = null; // Initialize it to null so it can be used later
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: mediaPlayer = null i think is useless

Answer (score 1):

Are you planning on reusing the player again, or are you done with the player? If you're done with the player, call release() and not reset(). If you plan on reusing the player, call reset() and not release().

reset() resets the player to its uninitialized state.
release() frees all resources associated with the player.

Answer (score 0):

The [Media Player State Diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) shows, and also states:

> Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state.
>
> - Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.

That means, that after calling stop(), we should call prepare() on the same audio file if we wish to play it again. Otherwise calling start() again won't do anything.

As prepare() might throw exception, we should wrap it in a try-catch block, like this:

```
    public void stopAudio(View view) {
    mplayer.stop();
    try {
        mplayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("stopAudio", "Unable to prepare() mplayer after stop()", e);
    }
}
```