# mediaplayer stop and replay with different url

Tags: android-fragments, android-service, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am learning to implement mediaplayer service. MediaPlayerFragment has 3 url_selection buttons and one play/stop button. Using url_selection button, I set the URL for setDataSource. if play/stop button is to stop or play mediaplayer.

First click on url_selection and click on play/stop button will play and changes icon. If play/stop button again clicked or another url_selection is clicked media should stop and play/stop show stop icon.

play stop and url selection is working but. Once mediaplayer is stopped, for another url I am getting illegal exception. This could be because I am calling player.reset , player = null. But If I don't do this, player.setDataSource is failing.
Below is implementation snip:

```
    public static MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "started service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {
        Log.e("player_status", "" + player);
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL_NAME");
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.reset();
        player.setDataSource(url);
        player.prepareAsync();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("start", "" + e);
    }
    return START_STICKY;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "started service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try {
        Log.e("player_status", "" + player);
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL_NAME");
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.reset();
        player.setDataSource(url);
        player.prepareAsync();
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("start", "" + e);
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        player.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("onPrepare", "" + e);
    }
}
```

I am doing wrong some where that unable to identify. Clicking play/stop should play if not playing (first time url1 if no url_section is clicked) and should stop if playing. And in both playing/stop state, url_selection should stop mediaplayer. User should click play/stop button again to start player with selected url.

not assigning null in stop gives error in setDataSource() and setting null off course throwing exception.

Comment: I referred below link and resolved the issue. Its an issue with reset() and release() issue. Now the service is working as expected.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223908/how-to-stop-media-player-properly-android